# histogram2d in tensorflow

Tags: plot, tensorflow, tensorboard

I want to create a histogram2d in Tensorflow. Something like this:
[image: example 2d histogram]

Preferably in Tensorboard, but it's fine if there's a simple solution without tensorboard.

Tensorboard seems to only plot 1D histograms/distributions. I have a solution using np.histogram2d and images, which I'll add as an answer, but it's far from ideal since I cannot show the axis or observe quantitative values.

Answer (score 2):

My solution involves using numpy's `np.histogram2d`, using `tf.py_func` to embed it within tensorflow and then plotting 'height' as grey_scale in an image using `tf.summary_image`.

```
def _histogram_2d(a,b):
  """
  takes two tensors of the same shape and computes the 2d histogram of their pairs
  """
  ar = a.reshape(-1)
  br = b.reshape(-1)
  aux = np.histogram2d(ar, br)
  return aux[0].astype(np.float32), aux[1].astype(np.float32), aux[2].astype(np.float32)

[H, xedges, yedges] = tf.py_func(_histogram_2d, [a, b], [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32])
      tf.summary.image('/2d_hist', tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(H,0),-1))
```

You get something like this:
[image: tboard_image_2dhist]

It does the job, but there may be something better.